# Can anyone help me fix grub?

Tags: grub2

I have decided to install Ubuntu on a USB stick and I have a SATA SSD with Windows 10 on it.

I mostly use Ubuntu now, 99.99% of the time, but I’d still want to keep the Windows installation around. I have the BIOS set to look for the USB medium first and then the SSD, however if the power fails or a restart is needed, I’m greeted with

[image: this grub screen which I can’t access remotely]

Apparently all I can do is go physically at the machine, type reboot and then spam the F8 key at startup to give me

[image: this Grub screen with the options needed]

In this case I just press enter and Ubuntu starts to boot.

I’d like to avoid that first screen, which appears for an unknown reason to me. Maybe Grub doesn’t know where to look.... I don’t know.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: You probably have grub in your internal SSD. See this [question and answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327229/installing-ubuntu-in-a-external-hard-drive-and-not-placing-grub-of-my-c-hard-dr) for how you could have avoided it in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! Very informative

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot without Flash Drive plugged in](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125494/cant-boot-without-flash-drive-plugged-in)

Comment: Yes but it seems this addresses only the causes not the repair. It seems boot-repair is the only way to go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), a program that repairs GRUB installations. It works from a bootable USB drive or from an installed Ubuntu system.

Comment: Thank you very much! This hopefully will do the trick!