# How to disable live system check at startup (booting) in ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: kubuntu, live-usb, 20.04

I am using Kubuntu, and one very irritating feature in (K)ubuntu 20.04 is the enforcement of live usb disk checking at startup, and if you are not fast enough to press ctr-c then it will take minutes scanning (which is not needed for 99.99999999999% of the cases).
So, is there a way to skip it by adding an option in the booting startup screen.
Also, I made a remastered iso file of my system and the problem still exist in the remastered version. Are there any settings in the system I can change to disable disk checking in startup for the remastered version???

Thanks.

Comment: If you create a bug report about this, please post a link to it, so that we can confirm it by marking 'Afffects me too'.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. There have been alot of complaints about auto disk check every boot. If you don't need the Live USB for installing Ubuntu you can do a full install to USB: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217832/how-to-create-a-full-install-of-ubuntu-20-04-to-usb-device-step-by-step . There is no Disk Check with a Full install, as well as other advantages: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231661/do-i-need-to-install-ubuntu-on-my-hard-drive/1231705#1231705

Comment: Have made a Bug Report, feel free to join in: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1875548

Comment: The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

Answer (score 6):

### Removing Disk Check on Persistent USB's

The command line option `fsck.mode=skip` can be used to skip the disk check.

The line `Checking disks: 0% complete` will still come up but **fsck** will not be run, nor will boot time be increased.

**mkusb** After the Persistent USB drive is created, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Persistent menuentry thus:

  linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed maybe-ubiquity fsck.mode=skip quiet splash persistent ---
- **Newer versions of mkusb already include this fix**.
- If you also wish to remove the **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen delete "maybe-ubiquity".

**UNetbootin** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the first menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open syslinux.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the default menuentry for (BIOS boot mode).

**Rufus** After creating the boot drive, open /boot/grub/grub.cfg as root.

- Add `fsck.mode=skip` to the Default menuentry for (UEFI boot mode).
- Open /isolinux/txt.cfg as root and add `fsck.mode=skip` to the "Try Ubuntu without installing" menuentry, (for BIOS boot mode).

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from BIOS boot by overwriting syslinux.cfg with:

```
default persistent
label persistent
  say Booting an Ubuntu Persistent session...
  kernel /casper/vmlinuz
  append  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper persistent initrd=/casper/initrd quiet splash noprompt --
```

The **Try Ubuntu / Install Ubuntu** screen can be removed from Rufus UEFI boot by removing "maybe-ubiquity" from /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: Thanks to brian-murray for fsck.mode=skip

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpfull.

Comment: Are these any settings regarding remastering (using remastersys derivative pinguy builder) to disable diskcheck in the final iso file

Comment: The boot option `fsck.mode=skip` is added automatically into  the some menu entries by [mkusb version 12.4.7](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&page=48&p=13951552#post13951552). It is available in the unstable PPA, `ppa:mkusb/unstable`

Comment: Thanks @sudodus: That was quick work. I understand that older versions just ignore this fsck command and are not affected.