# Eject internal SSD without manual unplugging

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

I am experimenting with a boot setup for an external drive. Most of the time, the operation ends up including OSes from my SSD (which I don't want) or messing the boot configuration of my internal SSD, which is an extra work.

To be extra safe, I just want to eject my internal SSD to prevent this from happening again. Disassembling my laptop to unplug my internal SSD manually is a lot of work.

Is there any way to eject my internal SSD in Ubuntu? I mean commands that would do "Safely Remove Hardware" kind of eject, not just unmounting them.

I have tried using `eject`, `udisksctl`, `udisks`, `hdparm` but it seems that none of these works for internal SSD, and `/sys/block/nvme0n1/device/delete` doesn't even exist

My internal SSD device path is `/dev/nvme0n1`

**EDIT 1:**

I am using Ubuntu Live CD to do this.

Another use case might be:

- Doing things (even stupid ones) on a live CD and have great confidence that anything you do there (including installing GRUB for another device) wont affect the internal SSD of the device you're using.

Comment: You may overestimate the difficulty to unplug the internal drive. It is very different between computers, how tricky (and time-consuming) it is, but it is worth trying, if you cannot find a way to disable it via the computer's UEFI/BIOS menus.

Comment: @sudodus I know its not that difficult, I have done it several times. But it isn't what I want to do every time bcs I need tools and time for it.

Comment: An alternative might be to get a old computer for development and testing (not too old, it should be able to run current versions of Ubuntu, so at least with a  Core2Duo processor or equivalent and at least 2 GB of RAM, 4 GB of RAM is much better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu in a external hard drive and NOT placing GRUB of my C: hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327229/installing-ubuntu-in-a-external-hard-drive-and-not-placing-grub-of-my-c-hard-dr)

Comment: @user68186 thank you, this is helpful for me even if it doesn't exactly answer the question :)

Comment: No need to thank me. You can up-vote the answers you find helpful when you have sufficient reputation.