# Edit permanently .bashrc

Tags: bashrc

I am a beginner Ubuntu user. I am booting Ubuntu from an USB flash drive and I need to edit the .bashrc file but every time I shut down or restart the computer the edits I made disappear.
Is it possibile to make the edit permanently?

To be completely clear when I boot Ubuntu i choose the option "Try Ubuntu" and not "Install Ubuntu" since do not want to partition the mail hard disk.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327229/installing-ubuntu-in-a-external-hard-drive-and-not-placing-grub-of-my-c-hard-dr/327452#327452) for how to create an USB drive with full installation of Ubuntu. Also take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295701/what-would-be-the-differences-between-a-persistent-usb-live-session-and-a-instal/295776#295776).

Comment: Try Ubuntu is temporary. Like other portable OSs, the filesystem runs off RAM. When shutting down, nothing is saved.

Answer (score 18):

"Try Ubuntu" is a live session that loads a "clean" copy of Ubuntu every time that you boot it.

**Changes that you make are not permanent.**

However you can install Ubuntu to the USB, which will retain your changes just like any other installation.

You can also use Rufus to create a bootable USB with [persistence](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397481/how-to-make-a-persistent-live-ubuntu-usb-with-more-than-4gb).