# Grub accidentally installed on internal hard drive after Ubuntu installation on external hard drive

Tags: boot, grub2, external-hdd

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on an external hard drive. it works perfectly fine but I if I unplug the external hard drive grub still shows up(but it's like a terminal). also in the boot menu there are two devices with the same name(the internal hard drive), one is Windows and one is grub. I think that I accidentally installed Ubuntu on the external hard drive but grub on the internal hard drive. is there a way to remove grub from the internal hard drive and install it on the external hard drive that already has Ubuntu?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but UEFI or BIOS boot. Make big difference on what you have to do. Most systems are UEFI and then you need an ESP - efi system partition on external drive with /EFI/Boot & /EFI/ubuntu folders. You can copy from internal drive or reinstall grub. You were bitten by this old bug if UEFI.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 External then boots like live installer in UEFI boot menu or from name or label of drive. If install only on external you can remove or continue to use boot from internal ESP.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327229/installing-ubuntu-in-a-external-hard-drive-and-not-placing-grub-of-my-c-hard-dr/327452#327452) for how to do this correctly.