# Ubuntu on external drive only boots up on the machine it was created on

Tags: boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi, external-hdd

I'm trying to create a external m.2 with ubutnu on it. On the external disk I created a new partition table using GPT and 3 partitions:

efi partition, fat32, flagged boot and esp

swap partition, linux-swap, no flags

main partition, ext4, no flags

Installed it as the something else option and mounted the main partition to /
I chose the bootloader location as the efi partition.
The external drive boots up without problems on the machine it was made, but not on another machine. Both machines are UEFI

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing Ubuntu in a external hard drive and NOT placing GRUB of my C: hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/327229/installing-ubuntu-in-a-external-hard-drive-and-not-placing-grub-of-my-c-hard-dr)

Answer (score 1):

A known problem on Ubuntu 22.04 (but you didn't identify the release you used).  Ubuntu 23.04+ using the subiquity installer had fixed this issue.

See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1396379 Grub installs to wrong disk. Do add yourself to the "Does this affect me?" list on the bug.
There are workarounds/solutions in the bug comments. Another problem is that your host system probably will not boot without the external device (since needed grub files are on it).

You probably have an empty efi partition on the second ssd.  Simply copying the first disk's efi to the ssd should allow it to boot on another machine.